# how to use Microsoft.Web.Administration properly to start an application pool from a web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I was tasked to find a way to restart an application pool from a web page. The IIS is hosted by our own IT department, so any security settings needed will be changed if necessary.

I am using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll and trying this for my local IIS (7.5):

```
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPoolCollection = serverManager.ApplicationPools;
            foreach (ApplicationPool applicationPool in applicationPoolCollection)
            {
                appPoolNames.Add(applicationPool.Name);
                // If the applicationPool is stopped, restart it.
                if (applicationPool.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
                {
                    applicationPool.Start();
                }
            }

            // CommitChanges to persist the changes to the ApplicationHost.config.
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

If I put this logic in a winform and run as local admin, my app pool in local IIS will be started. However, if I put the same logic in a webpage, it fails with error at this line with error:

```
if (applicationPool.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

I think this is due to security, but I already give a local admin user to my app pool. Is there a way to achieve this in a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the web page is not in the same application pool as the one you are trying to restart, which would not be a good idea (because the web page would suddenly lose its process host). So assuming it is a different application pool, then it is the identity of the web page's application pool which matters - this will need to have permissions to restart the target application pool.